# Perl module error on solaris-10

Tags: solaris, perl

I have installed perl and pm_dbdmysql perl module on solaris-10. I have a perl script which makes the mysql DB connection to a diff server and runs some queries and returns the results. Its working fine on linux(redhat) but when I am running the script on solaris-10 its giving me the below error:

> 2010-12-14 00:00:00 and 2010-12-14 23:59:59DAILY
>   INSIDE : 2010-12-14 00:00:00 -- 2010-12-14 23:59:59
>   install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/i86pc-solaris /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/i86pc-solaris /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1 .) at (eval 15) line 3.
>   Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed,
>   or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right.
>   Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Multiplex, Proxy, Sponge, Sybase.
>    at cerberus_report.pl line 114

Though dbd-mysql perl module is already installed.

> PKGINST:  CSWpmdbdmysql
>         NAME:  pm_dbdmysql - MySQL driver for the Perl5 Database Interface (DBI)

Is it something related to the path variables to need some other perl moudule dependency!

Answer (score 0):

From the [list of package files](http://www.opencsw.org/search/pm_dbdmysql/), it certainly seems like you'll need to add `/opt/csw/lib/perl/csw` to your `PERL5LIB`.